# DrawText(), DT_LEFT and colons moving to beginning of text?

Tags: mfc, drawtext

on some PCs I am finding that my calls to DrawText() result in colons being placed at the start of the text.

```
dc.DrawText( "Name:", &rText, DT_LEFT | DT_VCENTER | DT_WORDBREAK );
```

The output on my PC is

```
Name:
```

But on one PC in particular it is:

```
:Name
```

If I change DT_LEFT to DT_CENTER the colon appears at the end where it should. Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the line of code above wasn't entirely accurate. I was requesting the style of the CStatic control that I'd derived which had the DT_MODIFY flag set. On that one particular machine that resulted in the colon being moved.. So, to fix this issue I masked them flags with 0x0000FFFF and all is working fine.

Cheers
Sparky